# Limit the number of times an HTML5 video plays

Tags: html, loops, video

I know I can loop a video infinitely using the 'loop' attribute. 
But can I limit the number of times the video loops to perhaps 5 times?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to achieve this. Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
var iterations = 1;

document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {    

    if (iterations < 5) {       

        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        iterations ++;
        
        document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

    }   

}, false);
```

```html
<div>Iteration: <span id="iteration"></span></div>

<video width="320" height="240" id="myVideo" controls>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

## So whats happening here...?

1. We start by defining a variable called `iterations` which will store our current iteration. We set this as `1`.
2. We add an event listener to the `myVideo` video which fires when the video ends.
3. We then check that the `iterations` variable hasn't exceeded our number of plays which is `5`.
4. We restart the video by resetting the `currentTime` to `0` and then using `play()` function to start the video.
5. Then we increment the `iterations` variable by `1` and the whole process starts again until our `iterations` variable reaches `5` at which point it stops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A simple loop = '5' will be great to my case. Hope it will be in next spec. :)

Comment: @AsimKT I agree. I can't comprehend why something so simple wasn't implemented by standard.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your video has the "muted" attribute to autoplay it. The "on" "ended" is the key to knowing when the video has ended and then you can count the iterations. Also, currentTime = 1 will stop the video at the end and currentTime = 0 will stop at the beginning of the video.

```
let vid = $('body').find("#background-video");
let countPlay = 0;
$(vid).get(0).play();
$(vid).on('ended', function() {
    countPlay++;
    console.log(countPlay);
    if(countPlay <= 2){
        $(vid).get(0).play();
        console.log(countPlay);
    } else {
        $(vid).get(0).pause();
        $(vid).get(0).currentTime = 1;
    }
});
```